# Mixed content error with default CRA service worker

Tags: reactjs, nginx, service-worker

I created a default reactjs application using `npx create-react-app my-app --template cra-template-pwa-typescript` so this is a blank project. The only thing I changed is :

index.tsx

```
- serviceWorkerRegistration.unregister();
+ serviceWorkerRegistration.register();
```

I have no problem when running it in local using `npm run build` and `serve -s build`

When I try on production, I receive a mixed content error while loading the service worker.

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://example.com/service-worker.js' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://example.com/index'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

This problem doesn't appear in local since I'm using http but I don't understand why it appears in production. I'm sure it's a dumb error on my part I can't seem to find it.

my nginx conf is as follow:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name example.com;
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
                proxy_redirect / $scheme://$http_host/;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                proxy_read_timeout 20d;
                proxy_buffering off;
        }
```

`console.log(process.env.PUBLIC_URL)` gives me the correct url.

I tried fidgeting with the manifest.json, like change `scope` or `start_url`

I tried to change the scope as well in serviceWorkerRegistration.tsx

```
  navigator.serviceWorker
    .register(swUrl, {scope:"/"})
```